# libmysqlclient_r.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Dreamhost

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, capistrano, dreamhost

My rails app was working fine, but recently Dreamhost move out theirs servers (*something like that), now i can't deploy via capistrano..

i got this error message:

`libmysqlclient_r.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so`

raw version:

`[direct.soprojetos.com.br] executing command
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:199: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin in PATH, mode 040777
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/capistrano-ea5b03b4d38e/capistrano.gemspec:15: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin in PATH, mode 040777
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/kendoui_rails-dc276aceb446/kendoui-rails.gemspec:18: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin in PATH, mode 040777
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/pagseguro-fa2c22e88177/pagseguro.gemspec:15: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin in PATH, mode 040777
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:132: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin in PATH, mode 040777
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] libmysqlclient_r.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] /home/soprojetos/cap/releases/20130208183759/config/application.rb:14
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] /home/soprojetos/cap/releases/20130208183759/Rakefile:5:in`require'
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] /home/soprojetos/cap/releases/20130208183759/Rakefile:5
 ** [out :: direct.soprojetos.com.br] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 9957ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/soprojetos/cap/releases/20130208183759; true"
    servers: ["direct.soprojetos.com.br"]
    [direct.soprojetos.com.br] executing command
    command finished in 13266ms
*** [pushover:notify_deploy_started] rolling back
failed: "env PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/ sh -c 'cd -- /home/soprojetos/cap/releases/20130208183759 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp -- /home/soprojetos/cap/shared/assets/manifest.yml /home/soprojetos/cap/releases/20130208183759/assets_manifest.yml'" on direct.soprojetos.com.br
`

anyone can save me?

Comment: This is just one reason why Dreamhost is a very sub-optimal place to host Rails applications. If possible, you should try [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) as their free tier is comparable to the sort of service a paid Dreamhost account provides.

Comment: I have the same problem in Django on Dreamhost ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there was an OS upgrade and at some point something mysql related was either removed or not upgraded.

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.4:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
gem install mysql2
```

You may need to restart apache or whatever service is giving you the error.

Note that if you do

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql2
```

your system should tell you what you need to install to get the mysql2 gem to install, which in my case was the apt-get command above.

Answer (score -1):

Try swapping for the mysql2 gem https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2